# Java .contains cannot be used with charAt

Tags: java, string, parentheses

java: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to java.lang.CharSequence

```
boolean checkParentheses(String str) {
    Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();  

    String k = "({[";
    String s = ")]}";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length();i++ ) {
        if (k.contains(str.charAt(i))) {
            stack.push(str.charAt(i));
        } else if (s.contains(str.charAt(i))) {

            if (matching(stack.peek()) == str.charAt(i)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

what should I use instead of contains?

Comment: `k.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != -1`

Comment: `k.contains(str.charAt(i)` there is no `String.contains` that accept a char

Comment: maybe you should ask: what should I use instead of str.charAt(i). try s.contains(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))

Comment: Try using indexOf instead of contains. Contains requires a String (AKA CharSequence), but you have a char. Also you can refer : https://javamanikandan.blogspot.in/2018/01/java-string-indexof-method-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf` with -1.

Something along these lines:

```
boolean checkParentheses(String str) {
    Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();

    String k = "({[";
    String s = ")]}";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length();i++ ) {
        if (k.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) > -1) {
            stack.push(str.charAt(i));
        } else if (s.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) > -1) {

            if (matching(stack.peek()) == str.charAt(i)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could also use contains creating a new String. But that option is not that good (more ineficcient).

2nd option:

```
boolean checkParentheses(String str) {
    Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();

    String k = "({[";
    String s = ")]}";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (k.contains(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)))) {
            stack.push(str.charAt(i));
        } else if (s.contains(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)))) {

            if (matching(stack.peek()) == str.charAt(i)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The second option is rather ugly.

Comment: `String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))`

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza Thank you. Let met update the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I've a new error in the if statement containing "matching". Should I create a new question for that? https://pastebin.com/mXzULxn4

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, this one is closed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using indexOf instead of contains. Contains requires a String (AKA CharSequence), but you have a char. Also you can refer : https://javamanikandan.blogspot.in/2018/01/java-string-indexof-method-example.html
and 
https://javamanikandan.blogspot.in/2018/01/java-string-contains-method-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
k.contains(""+str.charAt(i))
```

the method contains works with String objects not Char